# How to stay logged in to Gmail after shutdown?

Tags: gmail, google-account

If I'm logged in to Gmail, and then I shut down my computer — the next time I turn it on, I obviously get logged out.

How could I keep myself logged in even after shutdown?

(I'm using Chrome, but solutions for IE or Firefox are fine as well.)

Comment: you check "stay signed in" http://i.imgur.com/kTjocTE.png

Comment: Dunno how I missed that... Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

To stay signed in after you close the browser (end the session), simply check the `Stay signed in`-checkbox on the login screen (as [Fischer said](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69791/how-to-stay-logged-in-to-gmail-after-shutdown#comment58205_69791)).
[image]

Comment: This answer is obsolete.